# Url for image stored in 'app/assets/images' - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm creating an API using rails. An image is uploaded to directory `app/assets/images/live/sample.png` (in my project directory named `rails-api`).

I cannot access the image on my local using `localhost/rails-api/images/live/sample.png`. What is the accessable url to that image? Do i need to include `assets` in the url? I tried to generate this url using `asset_path` helper.

Edit: I'm generating URL using `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('sample.png', host: 'http://localhost/rails-api/images/live')`

which generates

`http://localhost/rails-api/images/live/sample.png`

Comment: Try this ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('sample.png')

Comment: Didn't work. Threw `No route matches` error

Comment: Did you try image_tag("sample.png") ?
If it's in a subdirectory of assets, you should be able to access it with localhost:3000/assets/sample.png (3000 can be replaced with a different port number)

Comment: "An image is uploaded" - by a developer or by a user?